# res.render is not waiting for my request function to load

Tags: javascript, express, web-scraping, request

I have a router.post in my index.js and I am trying to get an input from the user and then direct the user to a different page called question.ejs. Question.ejs has a js called question.js that scraps user's relevant articles from the web and present them in html. The problem is that my question.ejs loads before my request is finished and I have no content to show for. Another odd thing, I have to press enter twice to make everything work... It's all very hard to explain but I made a video of my problem and I hope you can help me.

I've made several console logs and I have listed what they said and numbers next to **blank** indicates the order of console logs in my terminal.

**Here is my code for index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var news = require('../news.json');
var newsQuestion = require('../newsQuestion.json');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', {
       title: 'Express',
       news: news
   });
});

var parse = require('./parse');




router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.post('/questionUser', function(req,res){

newsQuestion.question.txt = req.body.id;
//var question = require('./question');

question = require('./question');
router.use('/question',question);

console.log("this is after router.use: ", newsQuestion.bbc.title); => 
3**undefined**

res.redirect('question');


});


module.exports = router;
```

**Here is my code for question.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var news = require('../news.json');
var newsQuestion = require('../newsQuestion.json');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');



var linkName = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/search?
q='+newsQuestion.question.txt+'&sa_f=search-product&filter=news&suggid=';
console.log('this is before request: ', newsQuestion.bbc.title); => 
1**undefined**

request(linkName, function (error, response, html) {
    console.log('This is inside of request but before the actual 
    scrapping'); => 4**undefined**

    var titleArray = [];
    var linkArray = [];
    var img = [];
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('a', 'h1').each(function () { 
           var title = $(this).text().trim();
           var link = $(this).attr('href');
           if (title.length != 0) {

               titleArray.push(title);
               linkArray.push(link);
           }
        });
        $('img').each(function () { //#siteTable is a the context and a.title is within the context.
            img.push($(this).attr('src'));
        });

        console.log('This is inside request: ', newsQuestion.bbc.title); => 5*undefined* 

        newsQuestion.bbc.imgUrl = img[0];
        newsQuestion.bbc.title = titleArray[0];
        newsQuestion.bbc.url = linkArray[0];
        console.log(newsQuestion.bbc.title); => 6*Chile moves towards legalizing abortion in limited cases*


    }
});

console.log('this is after request: ',newsQuestion.bbc.title); => 2**undefined**


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('question');
});
```

Here is my terminal:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2017.1.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Archie 
Jugdersuren\WebstormProjects\summaproject_trial3 - Copy (3)\bin\www"
this is inside parse
GET / 304 9.783 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.505 ms - -
this is before request:  undefined
this is after request:  undefined
this is after router.use:  undefined
POST /questionUser 302 14.087 ms - 60
GET /question 304 1.673 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.417 ms - -
This is inside of request but before the actual scrapping
This is inside request:  undefined
Chile moves towards legalising abortion in limited cases
```

Here is a video of me describing my problem (HD):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1VSu1DylFQ

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I figured it out.. it's sort of bootleg, I just made two separate functions.. one holding the request and the other holding the res.render, and I made sure that res.render just waits like 3 seconds when request is called. I figured that's enough time for request to finish.... If there is any better way please let me know.